# RHive rhive.connect() error Mkdirs failed to create file

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

I try to connect to Hive in RStudio:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME='/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hadoop/')
Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME='/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hive/')

rhive.init()

rhive.connect()
```

But `Connect()` command returns this error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/rhive/lib/2.0-0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a conf entry in the core-site.xml in the hadoop conf for the Hadoop cluster you want to connect to.

Comment: I know I'm late to the battle, but could you please explain a little bit more what actions are required ?